# How to create a new variable given a string variable of another dataset?

Tags: r, string

I have a dataset **data1** that contains the following information. 
L1_num is the numeric version of L1_str. Likewise, L2_num is the numeric version of L2_str.

[image]

I need to create a script that codes Level 1 (L1_num) and Level 2 (L2_num). This script will be used to code Level 1 and Level 2 using a **new dataset** that has variables Time, Bev and Where.

How can I automate such code? The script needs to be automated so it will work on any other datasets with different variable names and values.

**OUTPUT DESIRED**:

```
if (Time=='Morning' | Time == 'Afternoon') L1_num=1
if (Time=='Evening’)                       L1_num=2

if (L1_num == 1 & Bev == ‘Coffee’)                 L2_num=1
if (L1_num == 1 & (Bev == ‘Tea’ | Bev == ‘Water’)) L2_num=2


if (L1_num == 2 & Where== ‘Home’)                  L2_num=3
if (L1_num == 2 & Where==’Restaurant’)             L2_num=4
```

Here is the code to create data1.

```
data1 <- data.frame(L1_str=c('Time: Morning (30); Afternoon (15);', 'Time: Morning (30); Afternoon (15);', 'Time: Evening (45);', 'Time: Evening (45);' ),
                    L1_num=c(1, 1, 2, 2),
                    L2_str=c('Bev: Coffee (30);', 'Bev: Tea (20); Water (20);', 'Where: Home (15)', '   Where: Restaurant (25);'),
                    L2_num=c(1, 2, 3, 4)
)

data2 <- data.frame(Time=c('Morning', 'Afternoon', 'Evening', 'Evening'),
                    Bev=c('Coffee', 'Tea', 'Water', 'Soda'),
                    Where=c('Home', 'Home', 'Home', 'Restaurant')
)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how your desired result would look like?

Comment: I updated my original post to include desired script. Thanks!